# How to include an asp.net widget in an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

guys, sorry for the title of the post... i'm not so good in english, and it is a little difficult for me to explain.

I'm working on a Advertismnet web site.

I've to insert in different page something like a widget  ... a listview that show 5 rilevant (payed) ads ...

But as a "good" programmer, i know i don't write things more than once... So i'm asking you...  how to "include" a piece of code (aspx and codebehind) in different asp.net page  ?

I think you can answer me : "use master page and content page"... but each time, this "widget" will be in different place...

So... please give me the right way !
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into using an [ASP.NET User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx).

Comment: Yes... this is what i was looking for.. i didn't know them...great, thanks matthew..! ;)

Comment: Well, if it is that helpful, the little green checkmark next to my answer is calling you. :)